# online semi-supervised learning with incomplete input data

Tags: online-algorithms, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

Let's assume that one has the following inputs and corresponding outputs:

```
x1 = (a,b,c) with corresponding output y1, which is a number.
x2 = (d,e,?) with unknown output
x3 = (?,?,g) with known output y2, which is a number
```

and so on.

So, by "incomplete input data" I don't just mean that some input data is unlabeled but some data-points from certain data-vectors are missing and are sometimes labeled and sometimes unlabeled.

Is there at least one known online semi-supervised learning algorithm for this kind of "input data with gaps"?

So far I only found algorithms for online semi-supervised learning for "input data without any gaps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a new paper that does just this, however I have not read it carefully: [Max-Ordinal Learning](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6655987).

Another option is the [E-M algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm), which is commonly used with missing data.